# Callstack overflow on JSON .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, stack-overflow, callstack

I have a list of JSON objects that I loop through and then (using the jQuery Gmap plugin found [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/)) create markers for that object and add it to the map.

Problem is that in each browser I'm getting callstack overflow messages:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceede

in Chrome, and

> Too much recursion

in Firefox.

I have NO idea why or how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap().bind('init', function (evt, map) {
        var webMethod = '<%= NavigationHelper.GetFullUrl("Components/Services/storelocatorservice.asmx/GetStoresByAddress") %>';
        var webParam = '{ "address": "Vaartkom 31/9 3000 Leuven", "language": "<%= Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>", "radius": "15" }';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webMethod,
            data: webParam,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                //$('#map_canvas').gmap('set', 'MarkerClusterer', new MarkerClusterer(map));
                addMarkers($.parseJSON(msg.d));
            }
        });
});

function addMarkers(json) {
        $.each(json, function (i, m) {
            $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                'title': m.Name,
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(m.Lat, m.Long),
                'name': m.Name,
                'zipcode': m.ZipCode,
                'id': m.LocationId,
                'bounds': true
            }).click(function () {
                $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', {
                    'content': '<h3>' + m.Name + '</h3><p>' + m.ZipCode + '</p><a onclick="getDirections(\'' + m.Id + '\')">Route</a>'
                }, this);
            });
        });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: +1 for using the word "overflow" in your title :-)

Comment: Do you have any idea on which line in the JavaScript the exception occurs? Is it on the `addMarkers($.parseJSON(msg.d));` or some other place? It's difficult to debug unless you manage to replicate the issue on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I have successfuly recreated this on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Extortioner/jYVFz/) and the problem seems to happen the moment I call the addmarker from the gmap plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix, not that it fixes the bug itself it just prevents it from happening:
I have to set the bounds: false when adding a marker and then it won't overflow the callstack.